# Bibliography entry for document authored by a (sub)committee

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, citing

What's the idiomatic way to describe, in BibTeX format, a technical document without individual authors, which was created by a subcommittee S, of a committee C, of an organization O?

More specifically: Who would be the author? Who would be the publisher? And would I use additional fields?

Case in point: The ISO 10646 standard (the one which defines Unicode), [4th revision](https://www.iso.org/standard/68309.html) from 2016.

Comment: This would be easier to answer if you provided the specific document you want to cite. But in general, if the author is a group, I use the `author` field to denote the group. If there isn't a real publisher, I'd omit that.

Comment: @TH.: See edit. Also, "the group" - the committee? the subcommitee? And does the name include the containing entity? e.g. is it `author={S}` or `author={A, committee C, subcommittee S}` or `author={A, C, S}`?

Comment: I'd set `author="{International Organization for Standardization}",` i.e., I'd go for a "corporate" author. If that's too expansive, I'd settle for `author = "{ISO}",`.